# Is there a way to limit the cycle in EF Core to force include a certain depth

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get the invoice and item inside the included invoice that I'm trying to return

```
await _invoiceReadSet.AsNoTracking()
                        .Include(i => i.Currency)
                        .Include(i => i.Customer)
                        .Include(i => i.Salesman)
                        .Include(i => i.InvoiceItems).ThenInclude(ii => ii.Item)
                        .Include(i => i.InvoiceItems).ThenInclude(ii => ii.Invoice)
                        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Guid == guid, cancellationToken);
```

The reason for doing so is basically so I am able to do something like this for the related `InvoiceItems`

```
    public Guid InvoiceGuid { get; set; }
    public InvoiceDto Invoice { get; set; }
    public Guid ItemGuid { get; set; }
    public ItemDto Item { get; set; }

    public decimal Price
        => Invoice.Customer.PriceChoice == PriceChoice.Retail ?
                Item.RetailPrice : Item.WholesalePrice;
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal Total => Price * Quantity * Discount
```

I am trying to avoid persisting the price and total. As excepted this cannot work by default - I get an error that looks something like this:

> The Include path 'InvoiceItems->Invoice' results in a cycle. Cycles are not allowed in no-tracking queries; either use a tracking query or remove the cycle.

Am I missing something? Or is the whole approach wrong? What is it that I am missing to be able to do such thing?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion to use tracking?

Comment: It's the same issue, and I'd rather use notracking on my readcontext.

Comment: Why do not project via `Select` to DTO class?

Comment: How about removing `.Include(i => i.InvoiceItems).ThenInclude(ii => ii.Invoice)` - it is automatically done by `.Include(i => i.InvoiceItems)`. Also replace `AsNoTracking()` with `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()`

Comment: @IvanStoev I need the invoice inside the invoiceitem so I can use invoice.customer.pricechoice I am trying to avoid any unnecessary persistence in my database. thanks for the help

Comment: I'm not saying to remove properties from your model. Remove the `.Include` / `.ThenInclude` statements from the *query* which is causing issue. As I said, normally when your include `Invoice.InvoiceItems`, the `InvoiteItem.Invoice` is *automatically* included.